# Row-wise cross entropy loss in 3D tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I have a recurrent neural network, which outputs an output of shape `[sequence_length, batch_size, num_classes]` and I would like to apply `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` to every timestamp of the sequence, or to every row if you will (correct labels are the same shape). How is this possible without iterating over the sequence length which can be really slow?

And how to do accuracy while we are at it?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, broadcast is able to handle this just fine. I had problems because of wrongly formatted logits and labels.